# Learning TensorFlow from PyTorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I have mastered PyTorch proficiently. Is there any way or tutorial to learn TensorFlow efficiently?

Comment: https://keras.io/getting_started/

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this course provided by google.
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/first-steps-with-tensorflow/toolkit